# goto line of code failing to execute

Tags: c++, c, goto

I have always been taught to almost never to use goto statements in programming. However we are required to do so as part of my most recent programming project. I have an if/else statement with various goto statements, and the goto statements are failing to execute. I have no idea why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
       int myInt = XXXXXXX;
       if((myInt>>22) & 7 == X)
          goto a;
       else if((myInt>>22) & 7 == Y)
          goto b;
       else if((myInt>>22) & 7 == Z)
          goto c;
a:
    printf("this always executes\n");
    goto end;
b:
    printf("this never executes\n");
    goto end;
c:
    printf("nor does this\n");
    goto end;
end:
    //more code
```

A brief explanation of the bit shifting and such: We are implementing a computer processer, and need to look at the first 3 bits of a 25-bit opcode. So (myInt >> 22) & 7 isolates the 3 bits in the opcode.

Any ideas as to what is going on here?

Comment: What makes you think the `goto` doesn't execute? Also, the `printf` statements are either misleading or wrong: If the first `printf` prints, the second and third will print. Step through it with a debugger, that'll show you where execution is going.

Comment: What's the result you are getting and what's the result you wanted to get?

Comment: hmm.. did you try it with your printf statement above and not see the prints?  Does the code you're testing with have different code?  You should at least see fallthrough.

Comment: Your third `if` is identical to your first `if`, so `goto c` never executes ... and if `goto b` somehow does not execute, it will appear as though `goto a` always executed.

Comment: sorry about those bugs. I adapted my projects exact code to avoid posting my code to the internet and introduced bugs in the process. Its fixed now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with goto.  You've got an operator precedence problem.  Bitwise and (&) has lower precedence than equality (==).  As a result, you're actually doing `if ((myInt>>22) & (7 == X))`.

To fix it, just add some parens: `if ((myInt>>22) & 7) == X)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for seeing past those bugs I introduced by posting sample code. +1 and best answer from me.

Comment: +1 Nicely spotted. That's the reason I always use parenthesis with `&`, `|`, `&&`, `||`, `=`, `==` even when they aren't needed

Answer (score 2):

I see that `}` that makes me think that labels and corresponding `printf` are declared outside a function. Of course you can't do that.. they have to be inside a method anyway.

(it's just a guess, also because I see you've got other problems as other answers state :)

Comment: yeah, it is all within a bigger if statement. thanks for catching it

Answer (score 2):

The '==' operator has a higher precedence than '&' in C/C++.

Try  `if ( ((myInt>>22) & 7) == X)` instead